# laravel socialite facebook loging error This authorization code has been used

Tags: laravel-socialite

i am using lavel/socialite in laravel project version 5.4 
Now i am facing an error

```
ClientException
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token`
resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:{"error":{"message":"This 
authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException", "code":100,    
"fbtrace_id":"F7xwAj18Ez (truncated...)
```

some times it working and sometimes showing this error.
have any suggestions to solve the issue.

Comment: This means that the auth code you're trying to use to fetch the user's logged in data has already been used by the application.

Answer (score 1):

in some cases, you can use a simple condition

`if (!$request->has('code') || $request->has('denied')) {
    return redirect('/');
}`

because when you try more than once facebook will not allow for gave information request.